# How does the Java program know how to access the file?

Tags: java, command-line, arguments, stdin

I have been reading this book **Algorithms 4th Edition.** Its code examples take an input from the command line

```
String[] a = StdIn.readAllStrings();
```

and sorts them. The source code for StdIn.java is given in http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdIn.java . Source for heap sort is in http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/Heap.java but really isn't relevent.
The main function looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = StdIn.readAllStrings();
    Heap.sort(a);
    show(a);
}
```

There is no explicit reference to the args. Yet when i pass in a text file as an argument in the command line it works as advertised:

```
   % more tiny.txt
   S O R T E X A M P L E
   % java Heap < tiny.txt
   A E E L M O P R S T X
```

Can someone enlighten me how the program reads in the input when no reference has been given. Many thanks in advanced!

Edit: changed the link for stdin java. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got this rather wrong:

> *"The source code for StdIn.java is given in http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/In.java."*

Actually the source code for StdIn.java is http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdIn.java.  You were looking at the wrong class!

> *"Yet when i pass in a text file as an argument in the command line it works as advertised"*.

Actually, you are NOT passing a text file as an argument.  Really!

When you do this:

```
% java Heap < tiny.txt
```

the shell is opening the file, and passing the open file descriptor to Java.  Java wraps this file descriptor as an `java.io.InputStream` object, and makes it available for the application via the the `java.lang.System.in` variable.  That is what `StdIn.readAllStrings()` is actually reading from.

In fact, your `Heap` program has no command line arguments.  If you print `args.length` in the `main` method, you will see that it is zero.

Answer (score 1):

When in command line, passing a file as `< whatever` to the application means that the contents of the `whatever` file will be the input for the application. This means that the contents of `tiny.txt` (in your specific case) will become the t̶e̶d̶i̶o̶u̶s̶  user input of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the default constructor for the `In` class you provided, I assume  `StdIn` is just an instance which is default initialized. By this constructor, it reads from stdin. By redirecting stdin to be from a file (<), you are feeding the contents of the file to this reader which is simply reading the lines.

To be clear, the text file is not given to your program in the args array. That would be `java Heap sort.txt`. Instead the standard input stream is redirected to be from a file.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a term for the (<) in the command line? Cant seem to find any documentation online. Searching with special characters on google is impossible.

Comment: AFAIK It's simply called the "Input Redirection Operator"